# Python convert list into split lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

so I have been given the task of using an api to pull student records and learnerID's to put into an in house application. The json formatting is dreadful and the only successful way I managed to split students individually is by the last value.

Now I am at the next stumbling block, I need to split these student lists into smaller sections so I implement a for loop as so:

```
student = request.text.split('"SENMajorNeedsDetails"')

for students in student:
    r = str(student).split(',')

print (student[0], student[1])

print (r[0], r[1])
```

This works perfectly except this puts it all into a single list again and each student record isn't a set length (some have more values/fields than others).

so what I am looking to do is have a list for each student split on the comma, so student1 would equal `[learnerID,personID,name,etc...]`

this way when I want to reference the learnerID I can call `learner1[0]`

---

It is also very possible that I am going about this the wrong way and I should be doing some other form of list comprehension

my step by step process that I am aiming towards is:

1. pull data from system - DONE
2. split data into individual students - DONE
3. take learnerID,name,group of each student and add database entry

I have split step 3 into two stages where one involves my issue above and the second is the create database records

Below is a shortended example of the list item student[0], followed by student[1] if more is needed then say

```
    :null},{"LearnerId":XXXXXX,"PersonId":XXXXXX,"LearnerCode":"XXXX-XXXXXX","UPN":"XXXXXXXXXXX","ULN":"XXXXXXXXXX","Surname":"XXXXX","Forename":"XXXXX","LegalSurname":"XXXXX","LegalForename":"XXXXXX","DateOfBirth":"XX/XX/XXXX 00:00:00","Year":"XX","Course":"KS5","DateOfEntry":"XX/XX/XXXX 00:00:00","Gender":"X","RegGroup":"1XX",],

        :null},{"LearnerId":YYYYYYY,"PersonId":YYYYYYYY,"LearnerCode":"XXXX-YYYYYYYY","UPN":"YYYYYYYYYY","ULN":"YYYYYYYYYY","Surname":"YYYYYYYY","Forename":"YYYYYY","LegalSurname":"YYYYYY","LegalForename":"YYYYYYY","DateOfBirth":"XX/XX/XXXX 00:00:00","Year":"XX","Course":"KS5","DateOfEntry":"XX/XX/XXXX 00:00:00","Gender":"X","RegGroup":"1YY",],
```

Sorry doesn't like putting it on seperate lines

EDIT* changed wording at the end and added a redacted student record

Comment: Can you show a sample of what the `student` object looks like?

Comment: Please provide a concrete [MCVE], your explanation of the code is vague.

Comment: @timgeb That is not possible, there is no way I can give you a way to reproduce this. and I don't believe my explanation was vague, it was pretty detailed it outlined what i wanted to acheive and what I had done to try and acheive this. It also gave a code example of a loop and the reason why my solution didn't solve my problem

Comment: There is no way the code above "This works perfectly" works perfectly.

Comment: on questions like this always post an excerpt of input data which you can put into a minimal complete runnable sample code so we can execute and see input and result

Comment: @usr2564301 do you wish to actually elaborate and provide constructive criticism? also the "works perfectly" was sarcasm hence the apart from

Comment: That is not possible, there is no way I can give you a way to reproduce this <- If it is not possible to create a minimal example with sample data for this question, the question is off topic.

Comment: @timgeb any better? you should be able to reproduce the issue with the two dummy list items. obviously rather than sending the request you can just set the list manually. Also I have removed large parts of the list items so as to make it more minimal

Comment: Your sentence "The json formatting is dreadful and the only successful way I managed to split students individually is by the last value." looks very important, but I don't understand it. What is the json formatting, and why is it dreadful? What is this last value?

Comment: When you say the json formatting is terrible, do you mean that the result is invalid json?  If you are getting valid json back, you should be able to parse it into python objects and manipulate those.

Comment: In you example of something, you have an opening { and then comes a closing ]. This cannot be valid syntax of any sort.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh No it is all valid, just turning it into usable data is a nightmare. there is nothing that you can use to split the data on to seperate student records, apart from SENMajorDetails. I will take a look at turning it into python objects

Comment: @joe___pike If your data is a string, then try `obj = json.loads(json_string)`.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson you would think that a unique identifier I.E LearnerID or PersonID would be something logical to split a student on, unfortunately not as both of these appear multiple times if the student  has a sibling. if not then you would expect the team who implemented the api would add a character or string other than a , to split the students up. the only unique string I could find that only appeared once per student was SENMajorDetails. Also the not closing of the bracket is where i have removed some of the data in the student record (originally this was valid JSON)

Comment: I don't see the point in presenting us with invalid JSON when you had valid JSON originally. You are not making it easy to help.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh thank you for showing me a cleaner way to seperate each student record, I should be able to work with this easier now. the documentation wasn't very clear and used outdated libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify the resolution to my issue was to learn how to parse JSON propperly, this was pointed out by [@Patrick Haugh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6779307/patrick-haugh) and all credit should go to him for pointing me in the right direction. Second most helpful person was [@ArndtJonasson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9493582/arndt-jonasson)

The problem was that I was manually trying to do the job of the JSON library and I am no where near that level of competency yet. As stated originally it was totally likely that I was going about it in completely the wrong way.